# difference between Fedora's, openSUSE's, and Mandriva's initscripts?

Tags: fedora, opensuse, init-script, mandriva

I'm trying to figure out how the init system works for these distributions, but they seem to use different layouts... How do each of them work?

Comment: This is a QnA forum, not a mechanical-turk research site :) This would be a good time to read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several kinds of init systems, and some linux distros even offer more than one option. The most common are [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), [SysV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V), LSB, and [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), but there are others.

Here are some details on [init in OpenSUSE](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/opensuse/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.boot.html#sec.boot.init). Maybe if you have found others by now you can post back links.